# Error: use-life-cycle-interface requires type checking

Tags: typescript, tslint

I am trying to convert my typescript project to Webpack 2. One project went great but the other one is giving me the error in the title...

> Error: use-life-cycle-interface requires type checking

I have done a quick Google search and compared my tsconfig/tslint with the current project. Nothing seems different.

What do I have to do to remove this error? I couldn't find a TS error checking property.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue was an old version of TSLint I missed.